# jQuery mobile pageload and image processing

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, canvas

I'm using jQuery 1.8.2 and jQuery mobile 1.3.2 for a site. On one page, i'd need to wait for the whole page to have loaded to apply some javascript. I'm succefully using the `pageinit` event like so:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#filmes' ,function(){
    console.log('pageinit filmes');     
});
```

But this is closer to a `domready()` event than a `window.load`. 
So following the [jQuerymobile api](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageload/), i'd like to use the `pageload` event, like so:

```
$(document).on('pageload', '#filmes', function(){  
    console.log('pageload filmes');
});
```

But this doesn't trigger at all. The **#filmes** is the ID of the page where i wish to apply the js code. The `pageshow` event works fine:

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#filmes', function(){
    console.log('pageshow filmes');
});
```

But i still have some javascript problems, in my opinion due to the fact that the page hasn't finished loading when the js kicks in. The javascript operation is a bit heavy, i'm creating a canvas for each image on the page, duplicating the image and applying a multiply operation.

Here's the code (based on [Alberto Gasparin's article](http://albertogasparin.it/articles/2011/05/html5-multiply-filter-canvas/)):

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#filmes', function(){
    console.log('pageshow filmes');

    //multiply effect
    var els = document.getElementsByClassName("multiply");
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(els, function(el) {

        console.log(el); //test

        canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = el.width*2;
        canvas.height = el.height*2;
        el.parentNode.insertBefore(canvas, el);

        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.drawImage(el, 0, 0);
        imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        pix = imgData.data;

        multiplyColor = [255, 0, 0];
        function multiply(topValue, bottomValue){
            return topValue * bottomValue / 255;
        }

        for (var i = 0, n = pix.length; i < n; i += 4) {
            pix[i  ] = multiply(multiplyColor[0], pix[i  ]); // red
            pix[i+1] = multiply(multiplyColor[1], pix[i+1]); // green
            pix[i+2] = multiply(multiplyColor[2], pix[i+2]); // blue
            // pix[i+3] is alpha channel (ignored)
        }
        ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);

    });
});
```

Here's a [demo](http://kevinchevallier.com/dev/canitv2/) of all this. Scroll down, then hit the "Filmes" link on the top menu. The direct link to the page [is here](http://kevinchevallier.com/dev/canitv2/filmes/). If you open the console, you can see the messages i'm using for testing those events. I'm usually getting those bugs on the first load and then after a refresh it looks ok sometimes. Pretty random really. I'm guessing those operation take quite some cpu and browser work.

So after many testing and research, i'd like to know if i'm doing something wrong with jqm or the javascript operation or if i'm just doing something too heavy for the browser to render.

Comment: Why do you have your scripts within your body and not your head?

Comment: This is the way jquery mobile works, at first load, the srcipts are at the bottom. But when you load the content of another page via ajax, it adds a new <div data-role="page"> at the bottom.

Comment: Have you tried `pagebeforeshow`?

Comment: @omar just did, and it still gives me an `Uncaught IndexSizeError: Index or size was negative, or greater than the allowed value`. I noticed that the pagebeforeshow is triggered before the pageshow.